# Remote debugging with MinGW gdbserver

Tags: windows, mingw, gdbserver

I would like to debug a process which is running on development machine (as a remote machine) from my laptop using MinGW debugserver.exe. But I'm running in to an issue "*Error creating process "D:\remotedbg\XXX.exe", (error 50): The request is not supported*". I have built the XXX.exe using Visual Studio 2013 and trying to remote debug using MinGW gdbserver.

I just follow the guidelines at the link [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/gdbserver-example/) and I just executed the following command on the remote machine to start a gdbserver `C:\MinGW\bin>gdbserver.exe :2345 D:\remotedbg\XXX.exe` but ended up with getting aforementioned error.

If this is not feasible could you recommend me any way to do remote debug on windows. I actually want to attach a process which is running on remote machine from my host, and apply break points from my host gdb and control the outcome of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a Windows Firewall issue, then it is probably a mismatch between 32-bit gdbserver.exe and 64-bit XXX.exe  (or vice-versa).   The program I wished to debug on Windows was 64-bit, and I had a very similar problem to yours until I rebuilt gdbserver.exe to target "x86_64-w64-mingw32" instead of my original "i586-mingw32msvc" version.

But: were you not aware that [Visual Studio 2013 supports remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)?

Comment: @ Ryan v. Bissell Yes it was not a firewall issue and I had disabled that on my target machine. As you indicated the reason could be the binary mismatch. But I have started using WinDbg and it works fine for me now. Also I'm aware of the [VS2013 remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) and using that as well. Thanks for your input.